# Image takes up complete page instead of banner divider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to create a banner that blurs when you scroll, but when I try it, my image fills the entire page (it's behind all of the elements, but it still fills the page.) I want it in a divider located at the top as a banner.

**HTML/CSS**

```
<div id="banner-container" object="banner" style="height: 250px; width: 100%">
<div class="banner" style="position: fixed;   background-position: center; -webkit-background-size: cover; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: -1; background-image:url('http://s6.postimg.org/d7gcsqvdt/image.jpg')"></div>
<div class="banner-blurred" style="opacity: 0; background-image:url('https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/fit/c/1600/1280/gradv/29/81/40/darken/50/blur/50/0*I7mXgSon9oco-rim.jpeg')"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
    opacityVal = (s / 150.0);
    $('.banner-blurred').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
            if (s >= 100){
              $('.banner').css({'bottom':'auto', 'height' : '250px'});
            }else{
              $('.banner').css({'bottom':'0', 'height' : 'auto'});
            }
            opacityVal = (s / 150.0);
            $('.banner-blurred').css('opacity', opacityVal);
            });
```

as I understand from ( my image fills the entire page (it's behind all of the elements, but it still fills the page.) I want it in a divider located at the top as a banner.)  you need .banner class div to be fixed in the same position as id="banner-container" .. and you make .banner position fixed and bottom : 0 ... so you need to change it to auto and add height : 250px as your id="banner-container" .. I made that code  after scroll is bigger than 100px it will change .banner css

Comment: can you explain your correction? Why does OP's code, which doesn't touch css relating to size, not work?